# Launch Programm via Start-> Run

Tags: command-line

At the moment there are 2 versions of Matlab installed on my machine. Both versions have a function called `matlab.exe`. If I execute this command via **Start -> Run**, it launches the newer version. If the same command is executed on the **command line** the old version is started.

Do you mind giving me a hint what drives the "Run" window to execute a different command/path?

Regards,
Markus

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command line version searches the PATH statement

The RUN command searches the APP Paths first:
some info http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee872121%28v=vs.85%29.aspx